# Were Ornette Colemann's concerts ever noted to be incredibly or even unbearably loud?

Tags: jazz, live-music, sound, sound-quality, performance

I saw only one [Ornette Coleman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornette_Coleman) performance in my life, it was in the mid/late 1980's, and it was memorable event first because of the music and finally because of the incredibly loud volume that the speakers had been cranked up to for the final number.

It was in a large auditorium, and one-by-one audience members stood up and walked out, presumably because of the pain; it was too loud for me even with my fingers in my ears. We were just dumbstruck as we left, asking each other... *"Why???"*

A quick check of the internet has not turned up anything systematic about over-amplification as a notable characteristics of Colemann's concerts, so I thought I'd ask here to see if perhaps someone is more familiar with this or has some personal experience.

Comment: While this phenomenon is usually about recorded performance, dunno if it was affected by [loudness war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war), or an unfortunate volume mixer...

Comment: Meanwhile, googling "ornette coleman loud" returned at least 2 relevant results: [a quote by a pianist Thelonious Monk](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-people-ornettecoleman-factbox-idUSKBN0OR23220150611) saying "*He’s just playing loud and slurring the notes*" and [a recording from a live performance in 1968 using a musical instrumental "suona"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJePdnU_bwc) that is considered loud and high-pitched (warning!)

Comment: @AndrewT. interesting, thanks! Speaking of the suona: [How closely related in history, construction and use are these two instruments?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/62020/37941)